# How to make the input full-length in a column in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Bootply codes can be seen here =>   http://www.bootply.com/QpvisrtAJR

I want the input box to be longer, however, the `width:100%` doesn't work for it.. And I don't want to use `width: xxxpx` or `size=xxx` to make it longer because it will be un-responsive in different resolution..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: try http://www.bootply.com/QpvisrtAJR#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input rule isn't actually being applied. It is not specific enough so is being overwritten by a default bootstrap rule. Try this instead:

```
.form-inline button.form-control,
#contain_word
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/Qh2VwydnHx

Also you have a an erroneous character in your html where you give the input field an id. Should be:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="contain_word">
```

Not:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="contain_word`">
```

Comment: Thanks! I use `#contain_word` instead of `.form-inline input.form-control` but don't work...(I think ID selector is specific enough..) I don't know why.. http://www.bootply.com/QpvisrtAJR#

Comment: Also you had an erroneous character at the end of "id="contain_word`". Should be <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contain_word">.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the calc() method to have the input field 100% in width but still float left to the label.

**Updated Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/2K3ZIWsuWy**

Calc() is compatible with most browsers except Opera Mini. For Blackberry you still need -webkit.

**Check out the compatibility table here: http://caniuse.com/calc**

Answer (score 0):

You can add your class with a specified width

or override existing styles, but it is better to create your own style file

http://www.bootply.com/QpvisrtAJR#

```
div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">


            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 no-padding">
              <label for="contain_word`">Containing word(s): </label>
                <input class="form-control test" id="contain_word`" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">Clear</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```